# Loop through table and get latest value and date (Performance issues)

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

The goal of my stored procedure is when I send the `InstrumentID` to the stored procedure I would like to get back the `ChannelDescription`, the latest value (by `datetime`, and the value for that time)

I have 3 tables: `Instruments < Channels < Datum`

**Instrument**

- InstrumentID
- InstrumentName

**Channel**

- ChannelID
- InstrumentID
- ChannelDescription
- Scale

**Datum**

- DatumId
- ChannelId
- DataTime
- NumericValue

The following stored procedure works but it is super slow:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDataLastValue]
    @InstrumentID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        InstrumentId, 
        c.ChannelId, c.DataTime,  
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 4), (NumericValue / c.Scale)) AS NumericValue, 
        c.Diag, ChannelDescription
    FROM 
        dbo.Instrument 
    LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT 
            ChannelId,
            MAX(DateTime) as DataTime,
            (SELECT TOP 1 NumericValue 
             FROM dbo.Datum 
             WHERE ChannelId = t.ChannelId 
             ORDER BY DateTime DESC) AS NumericValue,
            (SELECT TOP 1 InstrumentId 
             FROM dbo.Channel 
             WHERE Channel.ChannelId = t.ChannelId) AS myinst,
            (SELECT Scale 
             FROM dbo.Channel 
             WHERE Channel.ChannelId = t.ChannelId) AS Scale,
            (SELECT Diag 
             FROM dbo.Channel 
             WHERE Channel.ChannelId = t.ChannelId) AS Diag,
           (SELECT ChannelDescription 
            FROM dbo.Channel 
            WHERE Channel.ChannelId = t.ChannelId) AS ChannelDescription 
       FROM  
           dbo.Datum as t 
       GROUP BY ChannelId) c ON c.myinst = Instrument.InstrumentId 
    WHERE 
        InstrumentId = @InstrumentID AND c.Diag = 0
    ORDER BY 
        ChannelDescription
END
```

Comment: your SP will not work when one of 3 sub queries return more than 1 result:  `(SELECT Scale FROM dbo.Channel WHERE Channel.ChannelId = t.ChannelId)` , `(SELECT Diag FROM dbo.Channel WHERE Channel.ChannelId = t.ChannelId)`, `(SELECT ChannelDescription FROM dbo.Channel WHERE Channel.ChannelId = 
t.ChannelId)`

Comment: @TriV On the other hand, ChannelId is most probably the primary key for Channel table, so this will not happen.

Comment: Wow the code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code might be faster, but does assume that the datatime for a specific channel is distinct:

```
SELECT 
    InstrumentId, c.ChannelId, d.DataTime,  
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 4), (NumericValue / c.Scale)) AS NumericValue, 
    c.Diag, ChannelDescription
FROM
    (SELECT 
         channelid, MAX(datatime) datatime 
     FROM
         datum 
     GROUP BY 
         channelid) latest
JOIN
    channel c ON c.channelid = latest.channelid
JOIN
    datum d ON d.channelid = latest.channelid AND d.datatime = latest.datatime
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Yest the datetime for specific data is distinct. It Channels don't have a date time.

Comment: Error follows Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'datatime'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'datatime'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'DataTime'.

Comment: Sorry i found the error. Thanks, I am still testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  
    chl.InstrumentId, chl.ChannelId, 
    tbl.maxdate,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,4),(dt1.NumericValue/chl.Scale)) as NumericValue, 
    chl.ChannelDescription
from 
    channelid chl
inner join 
    (select 
         instrumentid, channelid, max(datatime) as maxdate 
     from 
         channel ch
     inner join 
         datum dt on dt.channel id = ch.channelid
     group by 
         instrumentid, channelid) tbl on tbl.instrumentid = chl.instrumentid 
                                      and chl.channelid = tbl.channelid
inner join 
    datum dt1 on dt1.datatime = tbl.maxdate and dt1.channelid = tbl.channelid
where 
    chl.instrumentid = @instrumentid
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bot this does not work incorrect syntex near "dt"

Comment: @Beachmat Debugging is part of programmer's job.  We don't have the tables.  We don't have the data.  But we give you query that do as closely as your description.  But it's your job to troubleshoot why it doesn't work.  It's most likely just referencing wrong table, which you should figure out rather than saying "this does not work", and waiting.

Comment: Thanks for the help.